# iOS: Core image and multi threaded apps

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, core-image

I am trying to run some core image filters in the most efficient way possible. Trying to avoid memory warnings and crashes, which I am getting when rendering large images. I am looking at Apple's Core Image Programming Guide. Regarding multi-threading it says: **"each thread must create its own CIFilter objects. Otherwise, your app could behave unexpectedly."**

What does this mean?

I am in fact attempting to run my filters on a background thread, so I can run an HUD on the main thread (see below). Does this make sense in the context of coreImage? I gather that core image inherently uses GCD.

```
//start HUD code here, on main thread

// Get a concurrent queue form the system
dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue =
dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{

    //Effect image using Core Image filter chain on a background thread

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        //dismiss HUD and add fitered image to imageView in main thread

    });

});
```

More from the Apple Docs:

> Maintaining Thread Safety
>
> CIContext and CIImage objects are immutable,
>   which means each can be shared safely among threads. Multiple threads
>   can use the same GPU or CPU CIContext object to render CIImage
>   objects. However, this is not the case for CIFilter objects, which are
>   mutable. A CIFilter object cannot be shared safely among threads. If
>   your app is multithreaded, each thread must create its own CIFilter
>   objects. Otherwise, your app could behave unexpectedly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure how to say it differently: Each background thread needs to create it's own version of the CIFilter objects in your filter chain. One way to achieve this would be to make a copy of your filter chain for every background operation you `dispatch_async(...)`. In the code that you posted that might look something like this:

```
//start HUD code here, on main thread
// Assuming you already have a CIFilter* variable, created on the main thread, called `myFilter`
CIFilter* filterForThread = [myFilter copy];
// Get a concurrent queue form the system
dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{
    CIFilter filter = filterForThread;

    // Effect image using Core Image filter chain on a background thread

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        //dismiss HUD and add fitered image to imageView in main thread

    });

});
[filterForThread release];
```

What happens here is that `filterForThread` is a copy of `myFilter`. Referencing `filterForThread` in the block you pass to `dispatch_async` will cause that block to retain `filterForThread`, then the calling scope releases `filterForThread`, which effectively completes the transfer of conceptual ownership of `filterForThread` to the block (since the block is the only thing left with a reference to it). `filterForThread` can be thought of as private to the thread where the block is executed.

That should be enough to satisfy the thread safety requirements here.

Comment: Thanks. I will read your answer a few dozen times and perhaps it wil sink in :).

Comment: Here's an analogy: If you were writing a paper, and you wanted 5 different people to review/edit it for you (at the same time), you wouldn't make one print out, put the 5 people around it, and have them try to make edits simultaneously; You'd make 5 copies, and give each reviewer/editor the their own. Same idea here. You're giving each thread it's own copy of the CIFilter.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks, this saved me a bunch of time and reworking of other solutions. It works really well to handle filters in the background while keeping the UI moving.