# CIFilter appears to fail on GPU

Tags: ios, gpu, grand-central-dispatch, core-image

This is a weird one – I don't even know how to start.

I'm using a `CIFilter` to blur an image. Here's the essence of the code, implemented as a category on `UIImage`:

```
- (void)imageByApplyingBlur:(CGFloat)radius completion:(void (^)(UIImage *))completion {

  // If no completion, then nothing to do
  if (completion == nil) {
    return;
  }

  // If no radius, self is the result
  if (radius == 0.0) {
    completion(self);
    return;
  }

  UIApplicationState appState = [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState;
  CIImage *imageToBlur = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:self.CGImage];
  CGFloat scale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

  // Do the thread-safe CIImage blurring on a high-priority concurrent thread.
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

    NSDictionary *contextOptions = nil;

    // Always include the kCIContextPriorityRequestLow : @(YES) pair, because
    // otherwise, the foreground animation framerate suffers while blurring.
    if (appState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
      contextOptions = @{
                         kCIContextPriorityRequestLow  : @(YES),
                         // If we're not active, force CIContext to use the CPU renderer
                         // CPU rendering should be allowed even in the background
                         kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer : @(YES)
                         };
    } else {
      contextOptions = @{
                         kCIContextPriorityRequestLow  : @(YES),
                         };
    }

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:contextOptions];

    CIFilter *gaussianBlurFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
    [gaussianBlurFilter setValue:imageToBlur forKey:@"inputImage"];
    [gaussianBlurFilter setValue:@(radius) forKey:@"inputRadius"];

    CIImage *resultImage = [gaussianBlurFilter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];

    CGRect cropRect = {
      .origin.x = radius,
      .origin.y = radius,
      .size.width = (imageToBlur.extent.size.width - (2 * radius)),
      .size.height = (imageToBlur.extent.size.height - (2 * radius))
    };

    // Crop transparent edges from blur
    resultImage = [resultImage imageByCroppingToRect:cropRect];

    // Generate returnable UIImage (important to make the image "from" a CGImage, not a CIImage)
    CGImageRef resultCGImage = [context createCGImage:resultImage fromRect:resultImage.extent];
    UIImage *resultUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:resultCGImage
                                                 scale:scale
                                           orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    CGImageRelease(resultCGImage);

    // The completion block has to happen on the main thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      completion(resultUIImage);
    });
  });
}
```

About 90% of the time, this method works flawlessly. However, sometimes, it never submits a valid image to the callback block, and I see an incredible error log. The error log is long, so I'll wait until the end of the question to copy-paste it.

Some notes:

- Before I blurred on a concurrent dispatch queue, I blurred synchronously. It was slow, but I never saw this sort of issue. Could it be that something in the code is not OK with happening concurrently in the queue? Right when my app starts up, it submits two images to be blurred using this method, which is the only time I've noticed the method not working properly.
- [This question talks about requirements for using `CIFilter` from multiple threads safely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14109671/1292061), but as far as I can tell, I've satisfied these requirements. I could theoretically move to a serial queue for this, but I don't see why that would necessarily help.
- The errors I get are *really* odd – I don't know a lot about how CoreImage works internally, but this looks like code that's supposed to be compiled for execution on the GPU is invalid somehow. But only some of the time? I'm really stumped.

My question, then, is what is going on? And, ideally, how can I fix it?

Below is the relevant log output when I get no image:

```
liblib:3:15: error: :unkown type or function name: 'mix'
3:15: error: unkown type or function name: 'mix'
    return mix(y, z, step(0.0,x));
              ^
    return mix(y, z, step(0.0,x));
              ^
lib:lib:1:16:6:: error : error: non-void function should return a value
non-void function should return a value
vec4 compare (vec4 x, vec4 y, vec4 z)
     ^
vec4 compare (vec4 x, vec4 y, vec4 z)
     ^
lib:24:12: error: unkown type or function name 'tan'; did you mean 'tan_'?
    return tan(x);
           ^~~
           tan_
lib:51:26: error: unkown type or function name: 'max'
    return vec4(s.rgb/max(s.a,0.00001), s.a);
                         ^
lib:49:6: error: non-void function should return a value
vec4 unpremultiply (vec4 s)
     ^
lib:56:28: error: unkown type or function name: 'mix'
    s.rgb = sign(s.rgb)*mix(s.rgb*0.077399380804954, pow(abs(s.rgb)*0.947867298578199 + 0.052132701421801, vec3(2.4)), step(0.04045, abs(s.rgb)));
                           ^
lib:62:28: error: unkown type or function name: 'mix'
    s.rgb = sign(s.rgb)*mix(s.rgb*12.92, pow(abs(s.rgb), vec3(0.4166667)) * 1.055 - 0.055, step(0.0031308, abs(s.rgb)));
                           ^
filter:4:12: error: unkown type or function name: 'clamp'
  x = clamp(min(x, x.yzwx), 0.0, 1.0);
           ^
filter:1:55: error: unkown type or function name: 'max'
vec4 _ci_unpremultiply(vec4 s) { return vec4(s.rgb/max(s.a,0.00001), s.a); }
                                                      ^
filter:1:6: error: non-void function should return a value
lib:24:12: error: unkown type or function name 'tan'; did you mean 'tan_'?
    return tan(x);
vec4 _ci_unpremultiply(vec4 s) { return vec4(s.rgb/max(s.a,0.00001), s.a); }
     ^
           ^~~
           tan_
filter:3:26: error: unkown type or function name: 'mix'
lib:51:26: error: unkown type or function name: 'max'
  s.rgb = sign(s.rgb)*mix(s.rgb*0.077399380804954, pow(abs(s.rgb)*0.947867298578199 + 0.052132701421801, vec3(2.4)), step(0.04045, abs(s.rgb)));
                         ^
    return vec4(s.rgb/max(s.a,0.00001), s.a);
                         ^
lib:49:6: error: non-void function should return a value
vec4 unpremultiply (vec4 s)
     ^
lib:56:28: error: unkown type or function name: 'mix'
    s.rgb = sign(s.rgb)*mix(s.rgb*0.077399380804954, pow(abs(s.rgb)*0.947867298578199 + 0.052132701421801, vec3(2.4)), step(0.04045, abs(s.rgb)));
                           ^
lib:62:28: error: unkown type or function name: 'mix'
    s.rgb = sign(s.rgb)*mix(s.rgb*12.92, pow(abs(s.rgb), vec3(0.4166667)) * 1.055 - 0.055, step(0.0031308, abs(s.rgb)));
                           ^
lib:3:15: error: unkown type or function name: 'mix'
    return mix(y, z, step(0.0,x));
              ^
lib:1:6: error: non-void function should return a value
vec4 compare (vec4 x, vec4 y, vec4 z)
     ^
filter:4:12: error: unkown type or function name: 'clamp'
  x = clamp(min(x, x.yzwx), 0.0, 1.0);
           ^
lib:24:12: error: unkown type or function name 'tan'; did you mean 'tan_'?
filter:1:    return tan(x);
55:           ^~~ 
           tan_error
: unkown type or function name: 'max'
vec4 _ci_unpremultiply(vec4 s) { return vec4(s.rgb/max(s.a,0.00001), s.a); }
                                                      ^
libfilter::511::266::  errorerror: : unkown type or function name: 'max'
non-void function should return a value
    return vec4(s.rgb/max(s.a,0.00001), s.a);
                         ^
lib:49:vec4 _ci_unpremultiply(vec4 s) { return vec4(s.rgb/max(s.a,0.00001), s.a); }6
:     ^
 error: non-void function should return a value
vec4 unpremultiply (vec4 s)
     ^
filter:3:26: error: unkown type or function name: 'mix'
lib:56:28: error: unkown type or function name: 'mix'
  s.rgb = sign(s.rgb)*mix(s.rgb*0.077399380804954, pow(abs(s.rgb)*0.947867298578199 + 0.052132701421801, vec3(2.4)), step(0.04045, abs(s.rgb)));
                         ^
    s.rgb = sign(s.rgb)*mix(s.rgb*0.077399380804954, pow(abs(s.rgb)*0.947867298578199 + 0.052132701421801, vec3(2.4)), step(0.04045, abs(s.rgb)));
                           ^
lib:62:28: error: unkown type or function name: 'mix'
    s.rgb = sign(s.rgb)*mix(s.rgb*12.92, pow(abs(s.rgb), vec3(0.4166667)) * 1.055 - 0.055, step(0.0031308, abs(s.rgb)));
                           ^
lib:3:15: error: unkown type or function name: 'mix'
    return mix(y, z, step(0.0,x));
              ^
filter:lib1:1:6::55: error : error: unkown type or function name: 'max'non-void function should return a value

vec4 compare (vec4 x, vec4 y, vec4 z)
     ^
vec4 _ci_unpremultiply(vec4 s) { return vec4(s.rgb/max(s.a,0.00001), s.a); }
                                                      ^
filter:1:6: error: non-void function should return a value
vec4 _ci_unpremultiply(vec4 s) { return vec4(s.rgb/max(s.a,0.00001), s.a); }
     ^
filter:3:26: error: unkown type or function name: 'mix'
lib:24:12: error: unkown type or function name 'tan'; did you mean 'tan_'?
  s.rgb = sign(s.rgb)*mix(s.rgb*12.92, pow(abs(s.rgb), vec3(0.4166667)) * 1.055 - 0.055, step(0.0031308, abs(s.rgb)));    return tan(x);

                         ^
           ^~~
           tan_
filter:1:47: error: unkown type or function name: 'clamp'
lib:51:26: errorvec4 _ci_clamp_to_alpha(vec4 s) { return clamp(s, 0.0, s.a); }
                                              ^
filter:1:6: error: non-void function should return a value
: unkown type or function name: 'max'
vec4 _ci_clamp_to_alpha(vec4 s) { return clamp(s, 0.0, s.a); }
     ^
    return vec4(s.rgb/max(s.a,0.00001), s.a);
                         ^
lib:49:6: error: non-void function should return a value
vec4 unpremultiply (vec4 s)
     ^
lib:56:28: error: unkown type or function name: 'mix'
    s.rgb = sign(s.rgb)*mix(s.rgb*0.077399380804954, pow(abs(s.rgb)*0.947867298578199 + 0.052132701421801, vec3(2.4)), step(0.04045, abs(s.rgb)));
                           ^
lib:62:28: error: unkown type or function name: 'mix'
    s.rgb = sign(s.rgb)*mix(s.rgb*12.92, pow(abs(s.rgb), vec3(0.4166667)) * 1.055 - 0.055, step(0.0031308, abs(s.rgb)));
                           ^
filter:1:55: error: unkown type or function name: 'max'
vec4 _ci_unpremultiply(vec4 s) { return vec4(s.rgb/max(s.a,0.00001), s.a); }
                                                      ^
filter:1:6: error: non-void function should return a value
vec4 _ci_unpremultiply(vec4 s) { return vec4(s.rgb/max(s.a,0.00001), s.a); }
     ^
filter:3:26: error: unkown type or function name: 'mix'
  s.rgb = sign(s.rgb)*mix(s.rgb*12.92, pow(abs(s.rgb), vec3(0.4166667)) * 1.055 - 0.055, step(0.0031308, abs(s.rgb)));
                         ^
filter:1:47: error: unkown type or function name: 'clamp'
vec4 _ci_clamp_to_alpha(vec4 s) { return clamp(s, 0.0, s.a); }
                                              ^
filter:1:6: error: non-void function should return a value
vec4 _ci_clamp_to_alpha(vec4 s) { return clamp(s, 0.0, s.a); }
     ^
ERROR - could not find uniform for argument 0
ERROR - could not find uniform for argument 0
ERROR - could not find uniform for argument 1
ERROR - could not find uniform for argument 1
ERROR - could not find uniform for argument 2
ERROR - could not find uniform for argument 2
ERROR - could not find uniform for argument 3
ERROR - could not find uniform for argument 3
```

Comment: What version of iOS does this happen with?  Was this on Simulator?

Comment: This was iOS 8.3, on an iPhone 6. I have not seen the issue on the simulator, but I don't use it very often, and given that this is intermittent, I can't say for sure it isn't there.

Comment: Let me look into this...

Comment: Is the CIImage that you are converting to a CGImage large (i.e. bigger 4k pixels wide)?  If so then the CGImage that CI creates is a "proxy" that is not actually rendered on the GPU until the CGImage is drawn (presumably on the main queue)

Comment: No, the images are the same dimensions as an iPhone 5 screen's physical size, nowhere near 4k.

Comment: Hmm.  You mention that your app "submits two images".  I'm assuming that you app uses two CIContexts for these two images.  Does to problem go away if you use the same CIContext for both images?

Comment: Correct, it uses two contexts. I can try using a "shared" context.

Comment: Thanks for trying that. Please write up a radar so that Apple can track this issue.

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain how I could improve?

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to your main question but there is a much better way to "Crop transparent edges from blur".  Try this:

```
CGRect originalExtent = img.extent;
img = [img imageByClampingToExtent:originalExtent];
img = [img imageByApplyingFilter:@"CIGaussianBlur"
                          params:@{@"inputRadius" : @(radius)}];
img = [imageByCroppingToRect:originalExtent]
```

Comment: Though this doesn't address my question, it is interesting. Docs say that `ByClampingToExtent:` makes an infinite image on the edges. Is that to make the blur work properly at the image edges? And, yeah, that cropping makes more sense.

Comment: Yes.  The idea it to repeat the edge pixels so that transparency does not "leak" into the image.

Comment: In this post's code, the image it inset by 'radius' to avoid transparent edges.  This value is not sufficient given that CIGaussianBlur implements a gaussian function to approximately ±3 standard deviations.  (this is not related to the question of this thread but is important nonetheless)

Comment: `imageByClampingToExtent` does not appear to take an argument.

Comment: Another note, in case anyone goes this route: `imageByClampingToExtent` is iOS 8.0+ only. For backwards compatibility, you'll want something closer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18138742/1292061).

Answer (score -1):

While it's not the solution to the error, I definitely recommend `GPUImage` for GPU-bound image operations, which includes a very fast gaussian blur filter too.